# Mapping client role from external source in Keycloak

Tags: mapping, keycloak, roles

I successfully implemented `User storage SPI` in keycloak. Now I am able to do authentication from external REST source. Now I want to get client roles from external source. I am receiving a user entity as follows:

```
{
  "id": "78c8ee03-0bf8-422a-91ec-6241624c0683",
  "username": "kaushikam",
  .....
  "roles": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "heroes"
       "client": "heroes-client"
    }
  ]
}
```

In `keycloak` server, I have *manually* created a client with the name `heroes-client` and in that client I have added the client role `heroes`. Now I want to map the client role received from external source to the client role in the client named `heroes-client`.

I used the `getClientRoleMappings` in `UserModel` as follows:

```
override fun getClientRoleMappings(app: ClientModel?): MutableSet<RoleModel> {
        logger.info { "Calling getClientRoleMappings" }
        val userRoles = this.user?.roles?.filter { it.client == app?.name } ?: emptyList()
        val clientRoles = mutableSetOf<RoleModel>()
        userRoles.forEach {
            if (app != null) {
                clientRoles.add(app.getRole(it.name))
            }
        }
        return clientRoles
    }
```

But the above code is not being called. While `getRoleMappings` is called. Is there anyway to solve this issue.

You can get the whole source code of my work [here](https://github.com/nononsensecode/keycloak-user-storage-spi-demo)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I think there is currently no need of `getClientRoleMappings` method. My need can be achieved using the `getRoleMappings` method. I thought that method was only used for `realm roles`, but that's not the case. Below is the updated code for `getRoleMappings`:

```
   override fun getRoleMappings(): MutableSet<RoleModel> {
        val roles = addRealmRoles()
        return addClientRoles(roles)
    }    

    private fun addRealmRoles(): MutableSet<RoleModel> {
        val roles = mutableSetOf<RoleModel>()
        user?.roles?.forEach { roleDTO ->
            if (realm != null) {
                val realmRole = realm.getRole(roleDTO.name) ?: null
                if (realmRole != null) {
                    roles.add(realmRole)
                }
            }
        }

        return roles
    }

    private fun addClientRoles(roles: MutableSet<RoleModel>): MutableSet<RoleModel> {
        user?.roles?.forEach { roleDTO ->
            realm?.clientsStream?.forEach { client ->
                client.rolesStream.forEach { clientRole ->
                    if (client.clientId == roleDTO.client && clientRole.name == roleDTO.name) {
                        roles.add(clientRole)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return roles
    }
```

I have also updated the [repository](https://github.com/nononsensecode/keycloak-user-storage-spi-demo). You can see whole source code there